# How to install Resharper 9 into Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2017, resharper-9.0

I have a perpetual license (valid forever) for Resharper 9, so I want to install it into Visual Studio 2017, but the Resharper's installer doesn't detect VS 2017. The highest version of VS it detects is VS 2015.

I was wondering if there is any way to make Resharper 9 installer detect and install into Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: this was never possible to use an older R# version in newer VS versions, this will only cause issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981, can you please make that an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: no, this would be a low quality answer as all old documents about R#9  are replaced with newer ones. simply delete the question.